# FutureBuilder con StalessWidget

Tags: flutter

Hola tengo una pantalla con StalessWidget y utilizo provider, todo lo tengo separado por clases. en la pantalla principal tengo lo siguiente

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
   final contratos = Provider.of<ContratoService>(context);
   late Future<List<Message>> contract;
   contract = contratos.getContractosConCedula();
```

Mas abajo en mi pantalla llamo al future builder

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: contract,
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<List<Message>> snapshot) {
```

En mi clase ContractService tengo lo siguiente

```
Future<List<Message>> getContractosConCedula() async {
try {
  //String? cedula = await storagecedula.read(key: 'cedulatoken');
  String? cedula;
```

Que es donde llamo al API y traigo los datos, todo bien hasta ahi. pero en la documentación oficial de FutureBuilder indican que llame a la función en un StatefullWidget en el Init para que sólo se llame un vez y tenga los datos en Caché

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Pero en mi caso como tengo otra pantalla al ir y regresar al principal lo que hace es volver a llamar a la función **getContractosConCedula()**

Mi consulta es en caso que convierta el StatelessWidget a StatefullWidget como llamo a la función dentro del init si el provider lo llamo con el context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo así:

```dart
  late Future<List<Message>> contract;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final contratos = Provider.of<ContratoService>(context, listen: false);
    contract = contratos.getContractosConCedula();
    super.initState();
  }
```

No olvides del `listen: false`, ya que el provider no necesita escuchar cambios ahí, de lo contrario te marcará error.

Comment: gracias @diegoveloper y otra consulta, de ley debo usar StateFullWidget?

Comment: hmm no , desde el widget donde creaste el ContratoService, podrías llamar a `getContractosConCedula` al crearlo, y desde este widget lo haces stateless y usas Provider.of<ContratoService>(context). o context.watch para escuchar el resultado, ya ni necesitas FutureBuilder, hay muchas formas de hacerlo.

Revisa mis planes en el canal : youtube.com/@diegoveloper/,  hay acceso a discord donde compartimos conocimiento